# Restrict use of Team Foundation Server Build Controller

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

At a company we a running TFS 2013 Update 3. We are using a shared build infrastructure with multiple Team Project Collections, Build Controllers and Build Agents.

Now a project has requested a dedicated build machine for performance and specific configuration options.

*Is there a way in TFS to link the Build Controller to their team project and disallow other team projects to use this specific Build Controller?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JustTFS suggested tags is one way to go.  The problem I've found with that, is that build definitions by default are set to run on any agent regardless of tags.  So while you can tag an agent as ProjectX, and set all of ProjectX's builds to only use agents with that tag - ProjectA's builds which probably just use the defaults will also use ProjectX agent if it's available.

What I prefer to do nowadays (I used to use the tag approach), is to have a build controller for each Team Project.  This way ProjectX build definitions are set to use ProjectX controller.  And since ProjectA build defs are set to use ProjectA controller (or some common controller), ProjectA builds will never be run on ProjectX build server(s).

Comment: OK that's an idea. It wouldn't be hard to create a simple app that checks if all build definitions have a tag defined.

Comment: forgot about that one! was in a rush. you can also do something similar if you need to run multiple gated builds with large dev teams

Answer (score 1):

Build controllers are tied to a Team Project Collection, you can't really specify a particular project exclusively.

What you can do is use Tags, and tag a particular build server (Agent) with a Tag (ProjectA). you can then specify that tag within a Build Definition so that, that build will only run on a build server with that Tag.

The example shows my legacy code VS2008 Build Controller Tag. you can also filter Agents by specifying their name in the name filter

[image: Tag a build controller]

Comment: Thanks! I now about the use of tags and they can definitely be used for making sure the projects builds only run on controller X. I find it a shame you can't 'tag' a build controller so it can only be used from a specific project.